# Hash Map with Same key different value

Tags: java

In HashMap the older Key gets replaced with new when we put same key with different values... What if in get method i wish to retrieve OLD KEY'S VALUE... what will be code for to get older Key Value pair

Comment: What exactly do you mean? You want to get the key value that has already been replaced?

Comment: eventually, you can get the old value when calling `put`, see the javadoc

Comment: Basically HashMap overrides older value ryt.. and Get method gives us LATEST KEY VALUE pair (same key different Value) but I want OLDER KEY VALUE pair

Comment: @Daniele I doubt that. Could you link the specific javadoc you mention?

Comment: @KunalKadam write your own `Map` implementation then.

Comment: @Turing85 you can't even do that. Map, by definition, maps a key to a single value. You'd need to implement a Multimap.

Comment: Hm, the put method returns the value being replaced... https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put-K-V- but maybe I do not understand your question

Comment: @Turing85 it is the standard Map interface, the put method returns the value which was associated before the put operation. (see @ home comment for a link to the javadoc)

Comment: @Daniele I see. Thanks for the clarification =)

Comment: May I ask *why* you need the old key? This seems like an XY problem

Comment: When a value is *replaced*, the old value is gone. Your question is similar to the code `int a = 7; a = 23;` then asking how to get the old `7` value from `a`. You can't! That value was *replaced* and it is gone.

Comment: It's the task assigned to me just to check if I can think of some other method... Is there any way to get old Key Value pair ?

Answer (score 0):

Once you replace key's value there is no way to get the old value back. If you really want to store the old value you can make your own class which extends hashmap class, which is not recommended.

Comment: It's the task assigned to me just to check if I can think of some other method... Is there any way to get old Key Value pair ?

Comment: There is no way to fetch old key value pair.You need to design your own implementation by extending HashMap class.You can refer LinkedHashMap class to know about how this can be done.